# SQL Server: How to select column from two tables and show the same value of the closest date from the second table

Tags: sql-server, select

I have tried many ways with no result. I have two tables with different dates and values, I want to select both of them but as the next result, There is a way to do this?:

Table1

[image: Table1]

Table2

[image: TABLE2]

SELECT

[image: Table3]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you might want something like this

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.[value] AS [table1],
  t1.[date],
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 t2.[value]
    FROM [Table2] t2
    WHERE t2.[date] < t1.[date]
    ORDER BY t2.[date] DESC
  ) AS [table2]
FROM [Table1] t1;
```

Whether, in the sub-query, it should be `t2.[date] < t1.[date]` or `t2.[date] <= t1.[date]` I'll leave up to you in terms of the case of an exact date/time match between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

you can try right join as follows

```
SELECT  dbo.Table1.id, dbo.Table1.value1 as 'table1', dbo.Table2.date, dbo.Table2.value 
FROM
    dbo.Table1
Right JOIN dbo.Table2 ON
    dbo.Table1.date = dbo.Table2.date
```

Note this is just an example. You should add 2 tables each with 1 identical primary key, and have the same number of primary keys

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear on what basis should the rows of table2 be placed next to the corresponding row of table 1?
For e.g. Why should be the id 1 of table 2 be placed against id 1 and 2 of table1? Similarly, why the id 2 of table 2 be placed against ids 3,4,5,6 of table 1?

Comment: I can't explain it, my english is not that good. I have been close with datediff and rounding the table 2 date, but no that good.